# Send user to Security Boost speed settings

Tags: android, xiaomi

i am developing an android application an, in order to avoid that the os kill my background service, i realized that the app must to be locked. User could lock the app from recent aplications or by settings menu/security/Boost speed/Lock apps list (My test phone has MIUI 12.5.8 version - Andorid 11).

Are any way to send user to this settings menu screen by code?? The component name of these settings is knowed?

On the other hand, are any way to check if an aplication is locked by code?

I hope somebody have faced same issu in past and could respond my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out battery optimization settings, but this a default Android way for setting some restriction to apps. Some manufacturers are tweaking this feature by changing its behavior or adding more restrictions and there is no guarantee that below snippets will open this custom restricting feature instead of Android OS default one (or anything)

```
public static boolean isBatteryOptimizationEnabled(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            return pm != null && !pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.getPackageName());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("BatteryLife")
    @TargetApi(23)
    public static void goToBatteryOptimizationSettings(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm == null || pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
        else {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Still, disabling battery optimization in above way prevent my `ForegroundService` being killed after some time, it works on tested devices for days and weeks (but not sure which Xiaomi devices were tested)

Comment: Yes, i check if my application is not optimized and if in negative case i sent user to battery optimization settings as you comment. Also i send user to modify the battery optimization and set it to "not Optimized". I start foreground service, return "START_STICKY" on start command, request wakelock and so on. All recommend settings for foreground services and it works fine in most devices but i realized that in OPPO and XIaomi devices only works fine if mobile is charging. If it is not charging OS kills application sooner or later without call on destroy.

Comment: thanks for clarification, sadly I doubt these manufacturers reveal any API for their custom features... but when you find any solution please post in here, and I must check my soft on any OPPO device. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At least at the current moment, you can't because that activity is not exported and you can't open it from your code, here is the complete code (but it will throw you `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial... not exported`

```
public void ignoreBoostSpeed(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.optimizemanage.memoryclean.LockAppManageActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So the best thing to do is to open the `Security Settings` and guide the user to tap on the `Boost Speed>>Lock apps`

like this:

```
public void ignoreBoostSpeed(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.securityscan.ui.settings.SettingsActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```